# How do I write a hex literal in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, syntax

How do you write a hex literal in PostgreSQL? Like say I want `0xCC`, if I do;

```
SELECT 0xCC;
 xcc 
-----
   0
(1 row)
```

So PostgreSQL is parsing the `xcc` as an alias.

Comment: I needed to search for a specific hex char embedded in a string. Couldn't get concatenation in the WHERE clause to work, so ended up with `WHERE regexp_match(myfield, 'abc\u0018') IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Arbitrary Data / Integers (`int`)

You can write the hexidemical byte using [Bit-string constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS)

```
SELECT x'CC';  -- same as b'11001100'
```

Which is essentially the same as `bit x'CC'` returning a [Bit String Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html) but there is a cast available to `int` so you can do `x'CC'::int * 5`

## UTF-8 Byte Sequence

If the byte sequences is a valid UTF-8 character, you can also use [`E''` with a backslash-escape sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-BACKSLASH-TABLE) (**single backslash** `\`)

```
SELECT E'\x41';
 ?column? 
----------
 A
(1 row)
```

If the sequence is invalid, you'll get an error

```
# SELECT E'\xCC';
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xcc
```

## [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html)-specific.

PostgreSQL has a variable-length binary data type that allows arbitrary bytes. This type is called [`bytea`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html). You can move into this format using the [bytea hex format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html#id-1.5.7.12.9). In this we either use,

- Use a **double backslash `\\`**
- Use the cast to `bytea` from from the hex representation.

Here are both syntax,

```
SELECT bytea E'\\xDEADBEEF', bytea '\xDEADBEEF';
   bytea    |   bytea    
------------+------------
 \xdeadbeef | \xdeadbeef
(1 row)
```

### Storing large numbers

If you only need to store large numbers, rather than storing them as `bytea` I would check out [`pg_bignum`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/192746/2639) which stores them using the openssl implementation of Big Numbers.

Comment: is there a `casting or convet function` in postgresql equal to `x'CC'`?

Comment: @Null you can prepend the character `x`, then cast to a `bit` type (of the appropriate length) and then to `int`. For example, `SELECT substring('0x2ba41d8', 2)::bit(32)::int`. Beware that if you use a `bit` type which is too short for your hex string, it will be **silently truncated** to fit. See stackoverflow.com/a/17214093/648162 for details.